# yii authentication in page after user has logged in

Tags: php, security, authentication, yii

I'm new using yii framework in web development. I'm developing a website with a login page. I autenticate then user in a login page via password and username, then the user is redirected depending on his/her role. Now, I cant figure out how to validate the user in the redirected page ?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check in

Controller folder `siteController->actionLogin` function

there is a redirect URL is mentioned in this function `actionLogin ()`

```
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if($model->validate() && $model->login())
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
```

here you can get the login user's authentication details and also changed the redirect URL

Comment: I can redirect the user based on his / her role. What I can not understand is how to validate the user being in the redirected page.